# Magento 2 not showing CMS block list

Tags: magento2

I click on Content -> Block then block page show but block list not show and Pre-loader image continuously rounding.
Please look into this, what setting i need to do.
Here is scrrenshot link- http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d663n5487

Answer (score 0):

*Open the admin panel in Firefox and check for the errors using Firebug, may be you will able to trace the error.*

Comment: Hi Rakesh, i got error but what is the solution for it ? I tried to change  permission also.

Comment: Now getting one error- Magento_Ul/templates/tooltip/tooltip.html 404 not found.    Please anybody can tell me about this ? Thanks